# Multiple accounts with afew

Tags: email, notmuch

I've recently started using `Notmuch`. One thing I am missing is to setup `afew` to move messages between folders after tagging them with `Notmuch`. It all works fine with just one account under `~/Mail`, however, I want to operate on 3 separate accounts which would be `~/Mail/Account1` `~/Mail/Account2` `~/Mail/Account3`

How do I configure `afew` to move messages based on tags in specific accounts? `afew` just does not see anything in the subfolders/subaccounts.
Sample config:

```
[MailMover]
folders = Account1/INBOX Account2/INBOX Account3/INBOX

Account1/INBOX = 'tag:spam':spam
Account2/INBOX = 'tag:spam':spam
Account3/INBOX = 'tag:spam':spam
```

Obiviously `Account1/INBOX` is not a valid variable name. Perhaps `afew` cannot deal with multiple accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've talked about my issue with the creator of the application [here](https://github.com/afewmail/afew/issues/162).

Basically the idea is to use the `FolderNameFilter` with `maildir_separator = /` setting. This splits up your folders so that you can then reference your accounts like so:

`account1/INBOX` , `account2/INBOX` , `account3/INBOX`